# Can zlib remove padding without compressing the rest of the file?

Tags: c++, compression, zlib

I'm looking for a way to apply a specific compression strategy using zlib-1.2.5.
I need to force zlib to pack a file without actually compressing it. The only part I want to compress is 0 padding at the end of the file, so that the output file does not have it. The size of input files ranges from 1MB to 1GB, padding is 512B.
Is this achievable with zlib?

Edit:

The code I'm working on is based on Unreal Engine 4:
https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/Misc/Compression.cpp

```
static bool appCompressMemoryZLIB(void* CompressedBuffer, int32& CompressedSize, const void* UncompressedBuffer, int32 UncompressedSize, int32 BitWindow, int32 CompLevel)
{
    DECLARE_SCOPE_CYCLE_COUNTER(TEXT("Compress Memory ZLIB"), STAT_appCompressMemoryZLIB, STATGROUP_Compression);

    ensureMsgf(CompLevel >= Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, TEXT("CompLevel must be >= Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION"));
    ensureMsgf(CompLevel <= Z_BEST_COMPRESSION, TEXT("CompLevel must be <= Z_BEST_COMPRESSION"));

    CompLevel = FMath::Clamp(CompLevel, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);

    // Zlib wants to use unsigned long.
    unsigned long ZCompressedSize = CompressedSize;
    unsigned long ZUncompressedSize = UncompressedSize;
    bool bOperationSucceeded = false;

    // Compress data
    // If using the default Zlib bit window, use the zlib routines, otherwise go manual with deflate2
    if (BitWindow == 0 || BitWindow == DEFAULT_ZLIB_BIT_WINDOW)
    {
        bOperationSucceeded = compress2((uint8*)CompressedBuffer, &ZCompressedSize, (const uint8*)UncompressedBuffer, ZUncompressedSize, CompLevel) == Z_OK ? true : false;
    }
    else
    {
        z_stream stream;
        stream.next_in = (Bytef*)UncompressedBuffer;
        stream.avail_in = (uInt)ZUncompressedSize;
        stream.next_out = (Bytef*)CompressedBuffer;
        stream.avail_out = (uInt)ZCompressedSize;
        stream.zalloc = &zalloc;
        stream.zfree = &zfree;
        stream.opaque = Z_NULL;

        if (ensure(Z_OK == deflateInit2(&stream, CompLevel, Z_DEFLATED, BitWindow, MAX_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY)))
        {
            if (ensure(Z_STREAM_END == deflate(&stream, Z_FINISH)))
            {
                ZCompressedSize = stream.total_out;
                if (ensure(Z_OK == deflateEnd(&stream)))
                {
                    bOperationSucceeded = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                deflateEnd(&stream);
            }
        }
    }

    // Propagate compressed size from intermediate variable back into out variable.
    CompressedSize = ZCompressedSize;
    return bOperationSucceeded;
}
```

With params: input buffer size = 65kB, CompLevel=Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, MAX_MEM_LEVEL=9, BitWindow=15

Comment: The padding is up to the next 512B multiple or always 512B? Either way you can calculate it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Up to next 512B.

Comment: UnrealPak (Unreal Engine 4) uses zlib to compress assets. Assets are created by a third party software (out of control). Multiple assets are packed to a single pak file. Pak files are processed by deployment backend (out of control).
Deployment backend does not like long 0 areas in the binaries, so we have to trim it.
Unreal Engine by default does not compress pak files, so the easiest way is to just compress them. But this break diff patching - small change in on asset scrumbles the whole pak file.

Comment: So I want to reconfigure zlib to pack with very light compression that will only get rid of zeros in every asset and keep the rest of the file untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not.

If all you want to do is strip the zeros at the end, then that is trivial. It's a few lines of code. You don't need zlib's 18,000 lines of code to do that.

If you also want to restore those zeros to the file at the other end ("decompressing it"), that is trivial as well. Just send a count of the zeros that were removed, with that count in a few bytes appended to the end. On the other end, replace that count with that many zero bytes. Also a few lines of code.